# ms access query having

Tags: sql, ms-access, having

I have the following part from a big SQL which is working fine:

```
HAVING (((Format([AppointmentDate],0))<>[AppointmentControlDate]))) AS ControlDate
```

I am trying to add OR in my SQL but I am getting error.

```
Error 3122. You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 
<name> as part of an aggregate function.
```

The SQL looks like this:

```
HAVING (((Format([AppointmentDate],0))<>[AppointmentControlDate]))) OR (((AppointmentControlDate)=Format$(Date(),"00"))) AS ControlDate
```

Thank you.

If someone want all the SQL, please inform me to edit my post.

Comment: try `HAVING (((Format([AppointmentDate],0))<>[AppointmentControlDate])) OR ((Format$(Date(),0))<>[AppointmentControlDate]))) AS ControlDate`

Comment: tried yours, but I change it to this. It seems to working fine.

Comment: `HAVING (((Format([AppointmentDate],0))<>[AppointmentControlDate])) OR ((AppointmentControlDate)=Format$(Date(),"00"))) AS ControlDate`

Comment: @Santosh Do you think is fine?

Comment: As long as it works should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have an `AS...` in a `HAVING` statement.

You can remove `AS ControlDate`, and also almsot all of the brackets are unnecessary.

**Try this:**

```
HAVING Format(AppointmentDate,0)<>AppointmentControlDate
```

If you're still having problems, you edit your question to add the entire SQL statement and I will take another look.